# After inserting data into a table, it doesn't show the new data. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database management system. I used a standard SQL insert query.

The problem is the newly inserted data are not shown in the table even though the insert is successful. When I restart the computer and open the application again, the data shows up.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you made a `commit` after the `insert`?

Comment: Why is the question tagged sql-server?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`COMMIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm) after insert.

Use the COMMIT statement to end your current transaction and make permanent all changes performed in the transaction. A transaction is a sequence of SQL statements that Oracle Database treats as a single unit. This statement also erases all savepoints in the transaction and releases transaction locks.

Until you commit a transaction:

You can temporarily see any changes you have made during the transaction in the session by querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes. After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other users' statements that execute after the commit.

You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with the ROLLBACK statemen

Best practice is to use `COMMIT;` after every create, update, delete, modify statements.

Comment: I don't agree about "best practice to use COMMIT after every create, update, delete, modify..." actually that is a bit dangerous in many situations because it defeats the point of transactions.

Comment: @mrjoltcola: I meant, at the session end, it should be committed if any such statements are used!! You can edit my answer as appropriate.

Comment: @user3728385: You can accept it as answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

COMMIT your work. Likely you inserted with session A and queried with session B (another window) before session A had committed the transaction. Oracle will not display uncommitted changes to other sessions.

Oracle does not allow or support DIRTY READS. The READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level in Oracle does not follow the same implementation as SQL Server, for example. You will only see changes in the session (transaction) that performed them, until they are committed.

If you had queried the data from the same session that inserted it, you would have seen the data. If you are new to Oracle, you must understand Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) and how it differs from other database architectures.

As to why you saw the data after a reboot? You didnt mention what "application" you used. When you exit SQLPlus, for example, it auto-commits. If you want each statement to auto-commit you can use "SET AUTOCOMMIT ON" but that can be a bit dangerous because you wont be able to use ROLLBACK to revert erroneous changes.